# using std::sort with boost::bind

Tags: c++, sorting, boost, bind

I'm trying to use `boost::bind` with the `std::sort` function. I want to bind sort into a function taking no parameters and specify an int array to sort.

I'm running into issues with what to specify as the template parameter when binding sort, if I was using a standard container I would just use `std::container<int>::iterator` but since I'm using an array I can't figure out what to use.

Here's some code that illustrates my compile problem:

```
  const int NUM_VALUES = 100;
  int nums[NUM_VALUES];
  for (int i=0; i<NUM_VALUES; ++i)
  {
    nums[i] = NUM_VALUES - i;
  }
  boost::function<void()> sortHolder = boost::bind(&std::sort<type?>, nums, nums+NUM_VALUES);
```

Anyone know what template parameters to use here? Any other discussion also welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want "iterators" into an array, you use pointers to elements in the array.  Such pointers can be used as random access iterators:

```
boost::function<void()> sortHolder = 
    boost::bind(&std::sort<int*>, nums, nums + NUM_VALUES);
```

Comment: @wilhelmtell:  Sort of.  I don't have Boost on my lappy so I used the Visual C++ 2010 `<functional>` and swapped out `std::` for `boost::` in the answer.  Did I muck something up?  (Sincerest apologies if I did :'(  if so, feel free to post a correction and I'll remove this and upvote the correction).

Comment: @James the problem here is that `std::sort<>` is unresolved even with `std::sort<int*>`.

Comment: @James I think the standard allows implementation to add any number of template parameters, so long the the first parameters are those specified. But it does make a headache if you try to refer to the function. but i may be wrong here.

Comment: @wilhelmtell:  `&std::sort<int*>` should be unambiguous.  Both Visual C++ 2010 and EDG-based Intel C++ 11.1 accept it.

Comment: Actually I just used this and it compiles fine, problem solved. I swear I already tried using int* though, must have been having a vague moment. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @wilhelmtell:  I know for sure that an implementation can't add additional parameters to class templates; I'm unsure about function templates.  Even so, if `std::sort` _does_ have additional template parameters, I'm not sure how they would be deduced or what benefit they would offer.  Does this not work with some implementation?

Comment: @James g++ 4.2.1 snow leopard rants about `bind(<unresolved overloaded function type>, int [100], int*)`. but someone may well have slipped something into my cup of tea. :s

Comment: oh, and checked `<algorithm>` and there are no extra parameters in `std::sort` apart from the comparator overload. but passing in `std::less<int>` doesn't help.

Comment: @wilhelmtell:  Without an installation of g++ here, I can't investigate, but that sounds... unusual.  Does it list what the candidates are that cause the overload ambiguity?

Comment: @James, the compiler doesn't list candidates. but if i say `void (*foo)(int*,int*) = std::sort` and then say `bind(foo, nums,nums+NUM_VALUES)` then it compiles cleanly.

Comment: @wilhelmtell:  Interesting.  This is one of those times I wish I had a PC that ran something other than Windows ;-)